# DX force:source:pull ERROR: Cannot read property 'fileName' of undefined

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

What could cause this, and what can I do to fix it?

I think this stemmed from a change I made to a custom object, Invention__c. I deleted the default "Invention Layout" and replaced it with two others. When I did that I got the error "Entity of type 'Layout' named 'Invention__c-Invention Layout' cannot be found."

To fix that, I recreated the page layout and named it the same thing. Now I am getting this error. How can I recover the work I did in the scratch org? I don't mind making a new scratch org if I need to trash the current one.

Comment: OK, so I deleted that scratch org and created a new scratch org. I pushed to this new scratch org and then added fields and page layouts. That went fine, but in adding a new lightning bundle and an apex class I am getting the same error. What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem seems to be with the controller class I built. I really cannot fathom what is causing the error. I deleted the controller class and then tried sfdx force:source:pull and suddenly it worked! Somehow my class is being pulled after I deleted it? I don't understand this at all.

Comment: And now I cannot recreate the class. It is saying there is a duplicate on id value of <unknown>. Not only that, but I cannot edit my lightning components because it is saying "Failed to save myComp.cmp: invalid record id." Not only that, but my pull is not getting the components. What gives? Is this a bug with scratch orgs? Can I not do lightning development in scratch orgs?

Comment: After closing and reopening my scratch org and VS, I tried to open my lightning bundle. Dev console opened up, then said it could not read the file, and closed all my component tabs. Now the lightning component is completely removed. It seems the problem was in the components?

Comment: I have this same problem with another scratch org. I am beginning to believe this is a bug.

Comment: Did anyone find the fix? I am facing the same problem as well.

Comment: A guy named Patson Settachatgul reached out to me and said he has posted this question as well. He has done a lot more troubleshooting than I have, though. Take a look at his post here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=9060G0000005RR0QAM